# How can I list the contents of a ZIP file using Perl?

Tags: perl, zip

What I am aiming to do is pretty much what it says in the title.

I have the following line of code which simply prints out `[view archive]` and when I click it the browser just downloads the zip file.

```
print "\<a href=\"http:\/\/intranet.domain.com\/~devcvs\/view-file.cgi?file=$reviewdata{'document'}&review_id=$reviewdata{'id'}\"\>[view archive]\<\/a\>\n";
```

What I would love to do is to list the files contained within this zip file anywhere on the page, e.g. just underneath or even a new page which this link links to and takes the filename as a parameter.

I believe once this is done the browser should take care of the rest in terms of just clicking these files and viewing them in the browser as they will be pdfs and html files which I don't foresee any problems with.

I am sure there is a module that does this but I am unsure of how to accomplish my goal using it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well... the first step would be to identify that module... have you tried searching on CPAN?

Comment: yes but I couldn't work out how to do what I wanted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [`Archive::Zip`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Archive%3a%3aZip) :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw/ :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS /;

my $zipFile = 'someZip.zip';

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

unless ( $zip->read( $zipFile ) == AZ_OK ) {  # Make sure archive got read

    die 'read error';
}

my @files = $zip->memberNames();  # Lists all members in archive

print $_, "\n" for @files;
```

Comment: thanks! just trying to integrate it with my current code, got a few errors to work through.

Comment: got it work, thank you very much Zaid but this is the kind of output I am getting `[view archive] Archive::Zip::DirectoryMember=HASH(0x8b105e0) Archive::Zip::DirectoryMember=HASH(0x8b0f938) Archive::Zip::ZipFileMember=HASH(0x8b03c3c) Archive::Zip::ZipFileMember=HASH(0x8b151d8)` is there something I need to do to these hash values?

Comment: @martincarlin87 : I think you need to use the `memberNames()` method

Comment: ah, yes, sorry I'm not used to this module. Do you have any suggestions on how to make these printed file names links to the actual documents? Is it as simple as using `a href=....`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `Archive::Zip` certainly makes the code easier, and you should probably install that module if you are going to work extensively on zip files.

However, for those who prefer not to install anything, there is a way to list the content of a zip file just using the core module `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` (already part of any standard Perl distribution).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Uncompress::Unzip qw($UnzipError);

my $zipFile = '/path/to/zipfile.zip';

my $u = IO::Uncompress::Unzip->new($zipFile)
    or die "Error: $UnzipError\n";

my $status;
for ($status = 1; $status > 0; $status = $u->nextStream()) {
    my $header = $u->getHeaderInfo();
    my $zippedFile = $header->{Name};
    if ($zippedFile =~ /\/$/) {
        last if $status < 0;
        next;
    }
    print "$zippedFile\n";
}
```